# Reader how to catch eof

Tags: java, eof

I have a problem with the catch EOF character.

```
int y = read();
char x = (char) y;
System.out.println(y);
return x;
```

But when I get EOF it returns 10 and closes the stream. I tried with ready, but it doesn't work. :(
EDIT
How do I signal EOF to a program that is reading System.in from the 
NetBeans console?
I will try with eclipse console cuz other Readers works.
EDIT
Problem solved works on eclipse

Comment: what does `read()` do? is it coming from a `BufferedReader`?

Comment: Please provide some context. What is the object that you're calling read() on?

Comment: I can have BufferedReader, FileReader, InputStreamReader or sth else.

Answer (score 0):

Ready() won't help you with that since the stream can be read from, the next character just happens to be EOF.

I am not sure what you are looking to do, but if you want to prevent returning the EOF character, you should add a check for it.

```
int y = read();
if( -1 == y ) {
    // Handle it however you want
}
```

Comment: It works with FileReader but not with InputStreamReader(System.in). It doesnt work cuz i get y = 10 and stream after that is closed. I use CTRL+D to send eof. Maybe this is a problem.